# u-boot driver model: using sandbox_defconfig, "demo hello 5" got error "Command 'demo' failed: Error -22"

Tags: u-boot, device-tree, dm

u-boot version: 2021.07-RC3

**[Description]**
Build and run u-boot:

```
make sandbox_defconfig
make
./u-boot -d u-boot.dtb
```

Type the following on the command-line:

```
=> demo hello 5
```

I Got the following Error:

```
Command 'demo' failed: Error -22
```

**[Analysis]**
Index 5 is the device named 'hexagon' defined in `arch/sandbox/dts/sandbox.dtsi`:

```
hexagon {
        compatible = "demo-simple";
        colour = "white";
        sides = <6>;
    };
```

`device_probe` will call `of_to_plat`, which finally call `demo_parse_dt` in `drivers/demo/demo-uclass.c`.

```
int demo_parse_dt(struct udevice *dev)
{
    struct dm_demo_pdata *pdata = dev_get_plat(dev);
    int dn = dev_of_offset(dev);

    pdata->sides = fdtdec_get_int(gd->fdt_blob, dn, "sides", 0);
    pdata->colour = fdt_getprop(gd->fdt_blob, dn, "colour", NULL);
    if (!pdata->sides || !pdata->colour) {
        debug("%s: Invalid device tree data\n", __func__);
        return -EINVAL;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here, I got 0 for `pdata->sides`, and NULL for `pdata->colour`. Seem that `fdtdec_get_int` and `fdt_getprop` hadn't get the correct values from device tree.
I notice that `dn` here is in *int* type, but `dev->node_.of_offset` is in *long* type. So `dn` contains a truncated *offset* value. However, I'm not sure if the error I got is related to this.

Comment: It is preferable to send your bug report and possible patches to the U-Boot mailing list and to Simon Glass who is the maintainer for the driver model. See file MAINTAINERS.

Comment: Okay, I'll try.

Answer (score 1):

I face similar issue too.
I follow your clues and edit like this. It seems working.

```
int demo_parse_dt(struct udevice *dev)
{
    struct dm_demo_pdata *pdata = dev_get_plat(dev);
    int dn = dev_of_offset(dev);

    pdata->sides =  dev_read_s32_default(dev, "sides", 0);
    pdata->colour =  dev_read_prop(dev, "colour", NULL);

    if (!pdata->sides || !pdata->colour) {
        printf("%s: Invalid device tree data\n", __func__);
        return -EINVAL;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am quite new to u-boot. Anyone found better way, please correct me.